# Getting HTTP ERROR 500 for Wordpress (5.3.2)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

My wordpress(5.3.2) site is hosted in a cPanel shared hosting server,it has stopped running & now i'm getting HTTP ERROR 500, i've tried changing to default twentytwenty theme, disabling all plugins, and even falling back to wordpress basic .htaccess config, nothing works.

I'm not using any sub domain or multisites wordpress installation for this site, &
my hosting is responding fine except for this wordpress site i've mentioned.

does anybody have any idea what might be the issue here? i'm pretty confused now .

Comment: Checked the logs?

Comment: This is the last error log i just found out.
`[Sun Jan 12 05:49:22.221160 2020] [lsapi:error] [pid 22572:tid 47763022227200] [client 162.144.79.223:52444] [host www.mysite.com] Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_kses_normalize_entities() in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4316\n`

Comment: This function (wp_kses_normalize_entities()) should be in wp-includes/kses.php check if the file exists on your server. If not, try to re-upload this file.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered such problem ,but for me it was from hosting about permissions.i don't know if that is the same that is causing your problem or not.